# gnuplot - removing line title

Tags: gnuplot

I tried searching, but I couldn't find the solution for this particular condition. In my plot , I am comparing two traces. I am using a line graph and both traces are plotted with different colors.

```
plot "delay_try1.dat" using 1:2 title 'With CloneScale' with lines, \
     "normal_2.dat" using 1:2 title "Without CloneScale" with lines lc rgb "black", \
     "normal2.dat" using 1:2 title 'Without CloneScale' with lines lc rgb "black"
```

Using this plot command, I get 3 titles in legends and 2 are repeating ones. I just want 2 titles to appear and remove the repeating one. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: You are using 3 titles (1 for "With CloneScale" and 2 for "Without CloneScale" in the plot command. You can use only 1 for "Without CloneScale". But the legend will show only 2 types of graphs instead of the actual three.

Comment: Yeah I want all the graphs to be shown but only two legends.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

To accomplish this you should use the `notitle` tag.

```
plot "delay_try1.dat" using 1:2 title 'With CloneScale' with lines, "normal_2.dat" using 1:2 title "Without CloneScale" with lines lc rgb "black", "normal2.dat" using 1:2 with lines lc rgb "black" notitle
```

or a more general example;

```
plot 'File.dat' using 1:2 notitle
```

an alternative that is equivalent to `notitle` is to set the `title` to a zero character string;

```
plot 'File.dat' using 1:2 title ""
```

Answer (score 5):

If you had more untitled lines than titled lines, it's more convenient to disable titles by default using `set key noautotitle`:

```
set key noautotitle

plot "delay_try1.dat" using 1:2 title 'With CloneScale' with lines, \
     "normal_2.dat" using 1:2 title "Without CloneScale" with lines lc rgb "black", \
     "normal2.dat" using 1:2 with lines lc rgb "black"
```

Answer (score -2):

If you are not above a bit of trickery:

Just omitting the last "Without CloneScale" title will remove both title and line from the legend.
Setting the last title to a space will show the line and (seemingly) nothing before it in the legend:

```
plot "delay_try1.dat" using 1:2 title 'With CloneScale' with lines,"normal_2.dat" using 1:2 title "Without CloneScale" with lines lc rgb "black", "normal2.dat" using 1:2 title ' ' with lines lc rgb "black"
```

Comment: Omitting the last title will cause gnuplot to generate a default title, which is rarely desirable.  And having the line appear in the legend with no text seems undesirable, too.